# Insert random interger variable into array index in batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to select 1 of 10 random strings from a predetermined array using the code bellow.
When %Answer% is echo it prints "randomNumber".

Any ideas where I'm going wrong.

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a randomNumber=%RANDOM% %%10
set Answer=!foo[(%randomNumber%)]!
echo %Answer%
pause
```

EDIT: here is how I create the array (context: I'm trying to code a Magic 8 Ball)

```
set a/ foo[0]=Majic8BallDon'tKnow.Majic8BallSaysAskAgain..
set a/ foo[1]=You are not worthy of an answer..
set a/ foo[2]=You wouldn't understand if I told you..
```

and so on to foo[9]

Comment: You are doubling the percent symbols on the %randomnumber% variable which cancels out variable expansion.

Comment: even with 1 set of percent symbols the code doesn’t return the text set in the array.

Comment: 1. Do not use parentheses in variable names (but just `foo[...]`) as they may cause confusion with parenthesised code blocks! 2. Is your code located in a parenthesised code block?

Comment: `set a/` is invalid usage.  And if you were using the correct usage of  `set /a` you would still be using it incorrectly. The `/a` switch is used for evaluating an expression.

Comment: Removing the /a or a/ from the definition of the array has resolved my issue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices.

Use delayed expansion.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a randomNumber=%RANDOM% %%10
set Answer=!foo[(%randomNumber%)]!
echo %Answer%
pause
```

Or use the call command

```
set /a randomNumber=%RANDOM% %%10
call set Answer=%%foo[(%randomNumber%)]%%
echo %Answer%
pause
```

I don't know how you are creating your array, so this answer may need some tweaking.

Comment: I've tried both of the above. Delayed expansion gives me the result "ECHO is OFF" and the call command returns "%foo[8]%" instead of the value in the array. I will update the question with how I create the array now.

Comment: @Josh, your first code example showed that you were using parentheses to create your array variables.  Your new code showing how you are creating the array does not show any parentheses.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your comment

Comment: @Josh, you put parentheses in your first set of code.  But you are not using parentheses to create the array.  Do you know what a parentheses is?  ((((((((((()))))))))

Comment: Ah I understand your comment now. The parentheses were originally there as I thought they may have helped. Obviously not, thank you.